# Set variable with an array element

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with apps versions (v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v1.10.1, etc.).
Using `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL`, I have an arrays with the numbers as elements.
Any idea why I can't set the max of each element to a variable?

This is the code I use:

```
DECLARE x DEFAULT 0;

SET x = (
SELECT 
max(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(app_version, "\\d+")[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)])
FROM
'table_with_app_version');
```

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server is not BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardsql
create temp function normaizedsemanticversion(semanticversion string) 
as ((
  select string_agg(
      if(isdigit, repeat('0', 8 - length(chars)) || chars, chars), '' order by grp 
    ) || '..zzzzzzzzzzzzzz' 
  from (
    select grp, isdigit, string_agg(char, '' order by offset) chars,
    from (
      select offset, char, isdigit,
        countif(not isdigit) over(order by offset) as grp
      from unnest(split(semanticversion, '')) as char with offset, 
      unnest([char in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')]) isdigit
    )
    group by grp, isdigit
)));
create temp function comparesemanticversions(
  normsemanticversion1 string, 
  normsemanticversion2 string) 
as ((
  select
    case 
      when v1 < v2 then 'v2 newer than v1'
      when v1 > v2 then 'v1 newer than v2'
      else 'same versions'
    end
  from unnest([struct(
    normaizedsemanticversion(normsemanticversion1) as v1, 
    normaizedsemanticversion(normsemanticversion2) as v2
  )])
));
with test as (
  select 'v1.0.0-alpha' version union all
  select 'v1.0.0-alpha.1' union all
  select 'v1.0.0-alpha.beta' union all
  select 'v1.0.0-beta' union all
  select 'v1.0.0-beta.2' union all
  select 'v1.0.0-beta.11' union all
  select 'v1.0.0-rc.1' union all
  select 'v1.0.0' union all
  select 'v1.1.1' union all
  select 'v1.1.2' union all
  select 'v1.10.1' 
)
select string_agg(version order by normaizedsemanticversion(version) desc limit 1)
from test
```

with output

[image]

As alternative you can use below variation of final select statement

```
select version
from test
order by normaizedsemanticversion(version) desc 
limit 1
```